# How to state convergence through limit comparison test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am able to show convergence of the following series through the root test but am trying to practice the limit comparison test and can't figure out how to do it that way. 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n}{2^n+5^n}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To utilize the limit comparison test to prove convergence, you need to decide on a different function which is everywhere **bigger** than your original function.  Picking such a function sometimes requires practice or intuition, but in general it should behave similarly, but match a well known form that you are used to.

In your example., i see $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n}{2^n+5^n}$ and I think to myself that a geometric series would work well to approximate it with.  As this is a fraction, by dividing by larger numbers instead it will make it smaller, and I want to get something bigger, I can instead divide by something with a smaller denominator.

$4^n\leq 2^n + 5^n$ for all $n\geq 1$.

As a result, $\frac{3^n}{4^n}\geq \frac{3^n}{2^n+5^n}$ for all $n\geq 1$

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n}{2^n+5^n}\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n}{4^n}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{4}}=4\lneq \infty$

As a result, the original series converges.

Comment: What about if it was all the same, except the 5 was a 3 in the series I asked about? This diverges, but how so? couldn't you make the same argument?

Comment: For $\sum_{n=1}{\infty} \frac{3^n}{2^n + 3^n}$ I won't be able to pick an appropriate function to compare to.  However, there is a good test to use in this case.  Look at $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{3^n}{2^n + 3^n}$.  You'll find that the limit is equal to 1, and as such you are adding an infinite amount of sufficiently large numbers, causing the total sum to diverge towards infinite.

Comment: How did you compute that limit? That would be infinity over infinity, so you would have to use LH rule, right? that would get you (3^n ln(3))/((2^n ln(2)) + (3^n ln(3))) ? I dont see how you get limit = 1
Apologies for my lack of math format

Comment: Using lazy notation, notice that for $n\gg 1$ you have $3^n \ggg 2^n$.  In essence, the $2^n$ term is completely dominated by the $3^n$ term and so can be ignored.  For the sake of being more rigorous in my proof however, consider $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{3^n}{2^n+3^n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{(\frac{2}{3})^n+1} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{0+1} = 1$.  Having divided both top and bottom by $3^n$ gave us that step in the middle.

Comment: thanks, that helped a lot!

Comment: In general, for a problem like this, for any $c>0$, $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ with $\delta<c$, you can prove for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{c^n}{(c-\delta)^n+(c+\epsilon)^n}$ you can compare the function to $(\frac{c}{c+\frac{\epsilon}{2}})^n$ to prove convergence.  In your example $c=3$, $\delta = 1$, and $\epsilon = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare this series to $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^n}{5^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n$ using the Comparison Test since

$\hspace{.3 in}\displaystyle\frac{3^n}{2^n+5^n}<\frac{3^n}{5^n}$ for all n.

(You could use the Limit Comparison Test instead, but the Comparison Test is simpler.)